# Magento Website Crawl Issue - A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I am working on this site and some how (I don't know why) Google stopped crawling the home page URL (`http://www.indusuno.com/`)

When I search for the site in Google, it shows "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt Learn more".

I'm attaching the screenshot.

And also `index.php` is coming in search result URLs. Earlier we have blocked `index.php` from `robots.txt`, but now allow this.

Current contents of `indusunocom/robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /*SID=
Disallow: /catalogsearch/

Sitemap: https://www.indusuno.com/sitemap.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732697/magento-website-crawl-issue-a-description-for-this-result-is-not-available-bec Please do not cross post on different StackExchange sites or at least provide a link for context.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler actually this is the best place for this post and he was sent here from there.

Comment: @SR_Magento makes sense, the original post is the one that should be deleted

Comment: I added the current content of `robots.txt` to the question, so that it stays relevant after the issue is fixed. The spirit of Stack Exchange is that future visitors will also benefit from questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `robots.txt` is not correctly setup:

Current:

```
User-agent: *
...
```

What it should be:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Googlebot-image
Disallow:

User-agent: *
...
```

Make the change and then give it some time before your site gets crawled properly. Also, check your `webmaster tools` to make sure that there are no additional errors.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

[image]

> Earlier we have blocked index.php

This probably was the issue, and after you removed that rule, it took a while until Google crawled the site again.

Comment: Thanks for your precious comment, yes now it is working, may be this issues comes as we have blocked index.php.